# Similar detection in classification (Supervised learning)

Tags: svm, supervised-learning

If I have 3 classes A, B and C for training, and the SVM predicts that my testing sample belongs to class A (classification problem), then how can I know/ which technique I can use to find that within two remaining classes, which class comes closer to the result ? Likes A is the most similar, B is quite similar and C is not similar ? 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVM gives you such information (score for each class), as its application to multi-class problem is done by simply training multiple binary classifiers. Simply extract the decision functions and/or probability estimates, which should be provided in your SVM implementation.